# moving from end to beginning in rows database

Tags: android, database

I created a database in my application .
And take the values ​​of rows , use the following function .

dataBase:

```
qustion|answer_low|
  q1         a1
  q2         a2
  q3         a3
```

Method:

```
  public void getValueRow()
 {
    ArrayList<String> arr_q=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arr_al=new ArrayList<String>();

    SQLiteDatabase dataBase=openOrCreateDatabase(path, MODE_PRIVATE, null); 
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor=dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT qustion,,answer_low,", null);    
        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
         arr_q.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("qustion")));                  
        arr_al.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("answer_low")));


          }
        }
        dataBase.close();
    }
```

This function takes the values ​​of the database.
And stored in ArrayList ( as below)

```
 index   0   |1  |  2
 arr_q   q1   q2    q3
```

But I want the values
Saved from end to beginning

```
   index   0   |1  |  2
   arr_q   q3   q2    q1
```

What should I change in my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used `cursor.moveToLast()`

This will move the cursor to the last row.

### Like so

```
     cursor.moveToLast()

     while (cursor.moveToPrevious())
    {
     arr_q.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("qustion")));                  
     arr_al.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("answer_low")));

      }
```

Comment: If your cursor moveToLast() then you need to use cursor.moveToPrevious()instead of  cursor.moveToNext()

Comment: nice..+1 from my side.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (cursor.moveToLast(); !cursor.isBeforeFirst(); cursor.moveToPrevious()) {


   arr_q.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("qustion")));                  
     arr_al.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("answer_low")));




    // get stuff from the cursor 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the query to bring the results in the exact order I need the data with an ORDER BY clause.

```
cursor=dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT qustion,,answer_low ORDER BY qustion",null);
```

Comment: It was very interesting for me .
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can use `cursor.moveToLast()` to move the control to the last row and then iterating using `cursor.moveToPrevious()`

```
cursor.moveToLast();

while (cursor.moveToPrevious())
{
    arr_q.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("qustion")));                  
    arr_al.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("answer_low")));


}
```

Refer [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) class